# How to set properties in a custom WebViewPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a very basic custom `WebViewPage` class in which I want to assign a value to a custom property. Here's my code:

```
public abstract class WebViewPage :
    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage {
    public Employee UserPrincipal { get; set; }

    public override void Execute() {
        // Controller is also a custom class that contains the same property which is injected by
        // a custom ActionFilterAttribute. I've confirmed that the attribute is correctly updating
        // the property.
        Controller controller = (this.ViewContext.Controller as Controller);

        if (controller != null) {
            this.UserPrincipal = controller.UserPrincipal;
        }
    }
}

    <pages pageBaseType="X.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <!--System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage-->
```

From what I can tell the `Execute` method is not being called for some reason because I never hit any of the breakpoints I put in it. I have properly updated the Web.config to point to my custom `WebViewPage` and I can access the property from within the view, I just can't seem to set the property correctly.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your webconfig that references your `WebViewPage`.  Also you haven't defined the generic version (`WebViewPage<T>`).  You also probably need call `base.Execute()` in your derived types.

Comment: Also, don't be stingy with names. Call your page `MyWebViewPage` and your controller type `MyController`. That way, there won't be any confusion.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I've added the relevant portion of the Web.config. I did define the generic version, I just didn't see a reason to put it here as well when they're duplicates of each other.

Comment: I assume that your xml is in the `<configuration><system.web.webPages.razor>` node in the `web.config` located in the *Views* folder?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know why `Execute` isn't being called, but `InitializePage` *is*, so I overrode it instead. This works:

```
public abstract class WebViewPage :
    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage {
    public Employee UserPrincipal { get; set; }

    protected override void InitializePage() {
        base.InitializePage();

        Controller controller = (this.ViewContext.Controller as Controller);

        if (controller != null) {
            this.UserPrincipal = controller.UserPrincipal;
        }
    }
}
```